# Dialog width Material UI

Tags: material-ui

I am not able to increase the Dialog width in Material UI. It adds horizontal scrollbar to Dialog. Is there any way to increase the width of Dailog in Material UI? Can any on help?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Add two props `fullWidth` and `maxWidth="md"` in your `Dialog` component like this :

```js
<Dialog
  {...your_other_props}
  fullWidth
  maxWidth="sm"
>
  {/* Your dialog content */}
</Dialog>
```

You can change `md` to `sm`, `xs`, `lg` and `xl` as per your requirement.

Answer (score 23):

Just in case you don't want to use styles, here is how I achieved it.

```js
<Dialog
   onClose={handleCloseModal}
   aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
   open={open}
    sx={{
      "& .MuiDialog-container": {
        "& .MuiPaper-root": {
          width: "100%",
          maxWidth: "500px",  // Set your width here
        },
      },
    }}
  >
  
  <DialogContent />

</Dialog>
```

Comment: For me the best solution. Thank you!

Comment: Also for me the best solution

Comment: I think, mui should have this by default.

Comment: Wow.. Worked...

Answer (score 17):

As @mike partially mentioned you can pass down styles to specific child components (see available components for `Dialog` [here](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/#css)), the body of the dialog is a `Paper` component so if you set the width of the `Paper` the dialog will be that width

```js
//Set the styles
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  paper: { minWidth: "500px" },
}));

//Add the class to Paper
 <Dialog classes={{ paper: classes.paper}}>
```

This will make the dialog `500px` wide.

Comment: Or just width: "500px" & maxWidth: "100%"  to preserve the responsiveness when window is smaller than the given width

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Material-UI v1 documentation for Dialog](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/), the `maxWidth` prop is likely what you need. The [implementation of the Dialog component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Dialog/Dialog.js) takes in an enumerated list of `maxWidth` values `['xs', 'sm', 'md', false]`. The `fullWidth` prop is also available to take advantage of a full screen...likely most useful on smaller screens.

You can also get fancy and override the styles using either inline styles with `style`, the JavaScript keyword `className` to adjust the `class` in the DOM, the `classes` prop to adjust the classes inserted by MUI, or you can even adjust the width values in the theme using the `overrides` concept. [This is all laid out in the docs with some simple examples.](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overrides) It might take a few tries to target your customized CSS and make it work as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by adding the `PaperProps` property

```
 <Dialog
  {...your props}
  PaperProps={{
    sx: {
      width: "100%",
      maxWidth: "720px!important",
    },
  }}>
```

You can change the `maxWidth` as per your requirement.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above when I faced this issue. I had to resize the Dialog in order to fit the required data nicely.

The above options didn't work for me unfortunately.
I mean fullWidth maxWidth='md' was working but it was too wide for me...

What I ended up using is root class:

```
<Dialog open={open} className={classes.root}>
```

and in my styles I override like this:

```
export default () => ({
  root: {
    '& .MuiPaper-root': {
      width: '100%',
      maxWidth: '650px', // Set your width here
    },
  },
});
```

Just in case if someone facing the same issue, this was a working option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a style attribute with `overflowY: "clip"`  worked for me

```
<Dialog fullWidth>
  <DialogTitle>Title</DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent
     style={{overflowY: "clip"}}
  >
  ...
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

Full disclosure... I know just enough about Material-UI to be dangerous.